# How to change all classname elements of specific classname

Tags: javascript, html

How to change all classname elements of specific classname?

I mean, let's say I have 3 divs with classes "MyClass", and i want to change their classnames to "notMyClass" in JavaScript, how to do it?

```
<div class="MyClass">
</div>
<div class="MyClass">
</div>
<div class="MyClass">
</div>

<!--TO-->

<div class="notMyClass">
</div>
<div class="notMyClass">
</div>
<div class="notMyClass">
</div>
```

I know that it's very easy by calling element by it's id, but how to do it by it's classname?

Comment: Strongly related: [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](/q/195951/4642212). Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model): [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`NodeList`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/NodeList), [`classList`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [`DOMTokenList`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList). Use [`Array.from`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Answer (score 3):

Select all elements with the `MyClass` class with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then loop through each element (with [`NodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)) and use [`classList.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.MyClass').forEach(e => e.classList.replace('MyClass', 'notMyClass'))
```

```css
.notMyClass{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyClass">A</div><div class="MyClass">B</div><div class="MyClass">C</div>

<!--TO-->

<div class="notMyClass">D</div><div class="notMyClass">E</div><div class="notMyClass">F</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `querySelectorAll` method:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.MyClass')).forEach(elem => {
  elem.className = 'otherClass';
});
```

Note that I used `Array.from`, because querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, not an array.

Comment: [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) can be used here.

Comment: **Stop using `className`** unless you're creating a brand new Element from in-memory. Use what's best: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList